# change function not working inside document.ready ie7 , ie8

Tags: jquery, document-ready

hi i am using jquery 1.3.2 min

the problem is document.ready is not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

    alert("1");
});

    alert("2");


jQuery('.lob_dropdown').change(function(){

    alert("changed");
});
```

here only 2 is alerting , 1 is not alerting .

when change function inside document.ready it is not working . but out side the document.ready it is working correctly .

i have an error in ie console

[image]

can not understand why is this happening .. please help . thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you are using such an old version of jQuery?  If it is not a requirement - I seriously recommend upgrading to the more current 1.7+ versions...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your full html and javascript to reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, could this be causing an issue: *The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the <body onload=""> attribute.* -http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the last version of jQuery :

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

or with Google

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It will work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    alert("1");
    jQuery('.lob_dropdown').change(function(){
         alert("changed");
    });
});

alert("2");
```

You are accessing element which class is "lob_dropdown", before preparing dom.

so place it in ready, it will work.

Comment: functions inside document.ready is not working , please read the question..............

Comment: OP said pretty clearly that even just an `alert()` in document ready didn't work, so (despite the question title) getting the change handler to work is a secondary issue.